# Java Google App Engine Datastore put/get

Tags: java, google-app-engine

The Put :

```
    DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
    try{
        Entity e =  new Entity("Winners", "NFL" ); 
        String winner_game = new String("winner_" + input_game );
        e.setProperty(winner_game, input_win_value );
        datastore.put(e);
```

....

The Get :

```
    DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
    try{
        Entity e = datastore.get(KeyFactory.createKey("Winners",  "NFL" )); 
        String winner_game = new String("winner_" + i );
        if( e.getProperty(winner_game) != null )
        {
            Integer property = new Integer(e.getProperty( winner_game ).toString());
            return property;
        }
        else{
            return 0;
        }
```

...

The e.getProperty is returning null.....any ideas?

Comment: You don't need (or should use) `new String`, only `"winner_" + input_game`, also is `i` equals to `input_game`?

Comment: Yeah in the debugger winner_X is consistent.....

Comment: Can you test with a fixed String? Like `e.setProperty("winner_X", "Jon Skeet")` and `e.getProperty("winner_X")`?

Comment: yeah hard coding the value seems to work.

Comment: //Entity e = new Entity("Winners", "NFL" );
Entity e = datastore.get(KeyFactory.createKey("Winners",  "NFL" ));

Answer (score 1):

Do not create new String / Integer Objects. If you need to append something to the property name just do it directly.

```
Entity e = new Entity("Winners", "NFL" ); 
String winner_game = "winner_" + input_game; // Where input_game is "X"
e.setProperty(winner_game, input_win_value); // int input_win_value = 10;
datastore.put(e);
```

Same for retrieval:

```
Entity e = datastore.get(KeyFactory.createKey("Winners",  "NFL" )); 
String winner_game = "winner_" + i; // where i is also "X"
if( e.getProperty(winner_game) != null ) {
   // Casting is ugly but does the trick
   Integer property = (Integer) e.getProperty(winner_game);
   return property;
} else{
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Actually, it only seems winner_15 is being saved off.  I thought I would get

Comment: I am doing e=new Entity(...)  setting the property then puting it....I need to get it if it exists otherwise create it...????

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Your changes did make my code more manageable.  THANKS!

Comment: If you put a new entity with the same key it will overwrite the previous one (thus erasing / replace previously set properties). I'm not sure that I understand your workflow, but if you want to, for example, persist `NFL` with property `winner_1` and them later persist another property in `NFL` (say `winner_2`) without erasing `winner_1` you will need to get `NFL` set the property `winner_2` and put it back.

Comment: Entity e = datastore.get(KeyFactory.createKey("Winners",  "NFL" ));

Comment: ....catch (EntityNotFoundException e) {      Entity e_2 = new Entity("Winners", "NFL" );

Comment: Makes sense if you don't know if the entity exists or not...Problem solved?